# How does the collision of two protons forming a hydrogen-2 atom produce energy if a neutron is more massive than a proton?

Tags: nuclear-physics, astronomy, neutrinos, stars, protons

Wouldn't the transformation of a proton to a neutron require energy since the neutron is more massive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deuteron (nucleus of hydrogen-2) mass is $$M_{\text{deuteron}}<2M_{\text{proton}}~~~(\text{and of course}~M_{\text{deuteron}}<M_{\text{proton}}+M_{\text{neutron}})$$ because of [binding energy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binding_energy), which is always subtracted from a total mass of constituent particles (proton and neutron in this case).

The proton-to-neutron transformation occurs via the [inverse beta decay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_beta_decay).

Answer (score 2):

It is quantum mechanics : the [strong nuclear force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strong_interaction)  [binds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy) the nucleons in a potential well.

The difference between adding the constituent  masses and the mass of the nuclei gives the [binding energy curve.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve)

[image: binding energy]

This is an experimentally measured curve and can only be explained by the use of quantum mechanics.